# Phoenix on Hbase wrong results when region server is down

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-phoenix

I have a 4 node cluster.

When one of the node is down i see that HBase is running some compactions.
During this time if i execute Apache phoenix queries it is giving me wrong results.

Once the compactions are completed it is giving me correct results.
My replication factor is 3.

I am using HDP 2.6.

I have also observed similar issue immediately after data loading using org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool.